# How to begin profiling Android device with Xamarin 6.0.1 Community edition

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, profiling

I'm using Xamarin 6.0.1 Community edition.  I can't figure out how to start profiling my Android device.  I've followed the instructions on the documentation, but I do not have the same options as described in the documentation.

[Here is the Documentation I followed](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/deployment%2C_testing%2C_and_metrics/xamarin-profiler/)

> Launching from Xamarin Studio
>
> 1.) First, make sure you have your
>   application loaded in Xamarin Studio, and select the (default) Debug
>   configuration.
>
> 2.) Browse to Run > Start Profiling in Xamarin Studio, or
>   Analyze > Xamarin Profiler in Visual Studio, to open the Profiler, as
>   demonstrated in the diagram below:

I don't even have a Run > Start Profiling option to select.  And if I just open Xamarin Profiler, It doesn't recognize my Android device.  It only seems my mac.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a VS Enterprise license to access the profiler features in Windows or OS-X:

> NOTE: This is a preview release, however, you’ll need to be a **Visual Studio Enterprise subscriber** to unlock this feature in either Visual Studio Enterprise on Windows or Xamarin Studio on a Mac.

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/deployment%2C_testing%2C_and_metrics/xamarin-profiler/

> Xamarin Profiler works with a Visual Studio Enterprise license.

Ref: https://www.xamarin.com/profiler

Comment: That makes sense, last time I used it was 1+ years ago and at the time I still had an Enterprise license...  I no longer have one.

Comment: @LampShade There are only a couple of features that require an Enterprise lic, and this is one on them :-( They should do a test during the install to at least tell you that the feature will not work unless you update to and apply a Enterprise lic. within Xamarin Studio.

Comment: I agree completely, it annoys me when software doesn't do that and just doesn't work.  Especially in my case when I was at one point using that license, then stopped and the feature suddenly stopped working.  Oh well...